# How to get some Markdown from an external resource and render it to an HTML page?

Tags: html, markdown

I have an HTML file and a text in markdown. There is a way to import this markdown into the HTML file and mantaining the markdown format?
I've tried with `iframe`,`emble` and `import` tags inside the `main` tag and it didn`t work. Does anybody knows how to solve this problem ?
None of the proposed solutions here in stackoverflow solved my problem someone could help-me ?

Thanks guys

**Edited:**
I'm using: markdown-it, showdown.
https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it

https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

   

      <script type="module" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/12.2.0/markdown-it.js"></script>
      <script src="http://strapdownjs.com/v/0.2/strapdown.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.1/showdown.min.js" integrity="sha512-L03kznCrNOfVxOUovR6ESfCz9Gfny7gihUX/huVbQB9zjODtYpxaVtIaAkpetoiyV2eqWbvxMH9fiSv5enX7bw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/showdown/1.9.1/showdown.js" integrity="sha512-bvV1V1YSjP1fbfKJjTlNmdnUO2XpsLYUdKwmz5UXBi5U+x40rx9JpA0ooQUMZfpz1MaaBC0ydNLoC6r0sitPUQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <pre class="hljs"><code>
    <embed type="text/txt" src="markdown.txt" height="100%"> 
         <link rel="text/txt" href="markdown.txt"    height="100%">
      </code></pre>
    </main>
    <footer></footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTML and Markdown are both markup languages. A browser formats your document by interpreting the markup and transforming it into the rendered content. Browsers can't understand Markdown but they can understand HTML. So you'll need to transform your Markdown to HTML. How that is done depends on how your web site/app is designed. Are you doing things clientside or serverside? What languages are you using?

Comment: I using https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/markdown-it/12.2.0/markdown-it.js @PeterO.

Comment: Client side @Wing . But Iḿ also having problem in importing the markdown inside the html.

Comment: Ok, so you're using a library to try to parse your Markdown and convert it into HTML to render. Can you add this information to your question? Can you add what code you've tried so far? The most anyone can really do right now is point you to the documentation for that library and tell you to follow the instructions and examples.

Comment: Markdown It's documentation says you have to use the `render` function to convert Markdown to HTML. Where do you do this?

Comment: But it can be used in the embed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238223/discussion-between-wing-and-user2535338).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

You have two sub-problems here:

1. How do you get the Markdown content from the external resource?
2. How do you convert the Markdown content into HTML and render it into the page?

For your first problem, it looks like you've attempted to use [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe), [`embed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) and [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) to fetch the Markdown content. Ignoring the specific problems of each element, the common problem between them is you can't convert the fetched content into HTML. I'm not actually certain as to what the browser will try to do when the source is specified as a Markdown file – they'll probably all just try to render the plain text, but I haven't read the spec or tested this.

The second problem doesn't require any additional explanation.

## Solution

You can use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to fetch your Markdown content and read the response stream into text ([`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/text)). With this text you can pass it to your Markdown library and render the output HTML to your page. Below is a demo:

```js
const md = window.markdownit();

fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/master/README.md')
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = md.render(text);
  })
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@picocss/pico@1.3.3/css/pico.slim.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="output"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/markdown-it@8.4.2/dist/markdown-it.min.js"></script>
```